# why 'scanf' & 'getchar' adds newline to the input?

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

I'm trying to test this simple look up table, but can't understand why both `scanf` and `getchar` add the newline character (`'\n'`) to the input:

```
const int arr[10] = {1,0,5,7,6,4,8,2,9,3};
char digit;

printf("enter digits please\n");
digit = getchar();
while ((digit>='0') && (digit<='9'))
{
    printf("%d --> %d\n",digit,arr[digit-'0']);
    digit = getchar();
}
printf("bye bye!");
```

when runnnig this code, both with `printf` or `getchar()` the while loop executes just once, since the newline char (`'\n'`) is also stored in the char variable `digit`, & I can't figure out why.

Comment: Well, when you type input at this program, what do you type? What is the exact sequence of keys you press?

Comment: When you press the Return/Enter key, `getchar()` reads a newline character.

Comment: If you want to skip those, you need to add that logic to your loop, instead of just stopping the loop.

Comment: You can also solve this by just typing all your digits on one line.

Answer (score 0):

When you press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, it adds a newline to the input.  If you want to skip that, you need to skip that.  One easy way is by using `scanf` with a space in the format string, which skips all whitespace.  Use:

```
scanf(" %c", &digit);
```

instead of `digit = getchar();` in the two places you do that.

Comment: Don't recommend \*scanf, they are broken as specified and should not be used *ever*